# How to save returned value to variable with async/await using axios?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, response

So i have the following example:

```
const userApi = async () => {
    const res = await axios({
        url: URL + "getUserData",
        method: "post",
        data: { message: "getUserList" }
    });
    return res.data;
};

some_other_function = () => {
    const userList = [];
    userList = userApi().then(res => {
        // console.log(res) works here but i need to get the response data outside...
        return res;
    });
    console.log(userList); // It's still a promise... Why?
};
```

I can't get the response object into a variable, the promise doesn't resolve no matter what. How should i do this?

```
userApi().then(res => {
    userList = res //also doesn't work
    return res
})

console.log(userList)
```

Comment: Use async/await ?

Comment: I did and as far as I can see some_other_function is not async await.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a variable from within your function scope outside of the function. Try this instead and let me know if it worked.

```js
const userApi = async () => {
 const res = await axios({
    url: URL + 'getUserData',
    method: 'post', 
    data: {message: 'getUserList'}
})
 return res.data
};

let userList = []; 
some_other_function = async () => {
userList = await userApi();
 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
const userList = await userApi();
console.log(userList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
some_other_function = async () => {
    const userList = await userApi()
    console.log(userList)
}
```